# Music player that sorts by date modified

Tags: music, music-player

I have been using Ubuntu for about a week and am currently looking for a music player that can sort music by the date it was last modified.  This was a feature in Windows' Groove Music player.  I can't seem to find a Linux app  that will do this.  Can anyone suggest some suitable software?

Answer (score 0):

There's no GUI program that I know of but you can sort your files on command line, put them in a list and give that list to a music player.

1. `cd ~/Music`
2. `ls -t > MyMusic.txt`
3. `mpv --playlist=MyMusic.txt`

`ls -rt` will sort it by oldest first.